# how to break a paragraph into sentences in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to break a paragraph into sentences in jquery.
Lets say i have a paragraph

```
This is a wordpress plugin. its older version was 2.3.4 and new version is 2.4. But the version 2.4 had a lot of bungs. Can we solve it?
```

i want to break it into

```
This is a wordpress plugin.
its older version was 2.3.4 and new version is 2.4.
But the version 2.4 had a lot of bungs.
Can we solve it?
```

is there any solution for that.
i tried to use this function but it also separate sentence when a number came.

```
var result = str.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
```

Thanks

Comment: that's not simple.you may use a library

Comment: [nlp_compromise](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp_compromise) ([example](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp_compromise/wiki/Sentence-parsing))

Comment: NLP is a big task, so it's a big library.

Comment: @meagar that solution was also breaking numbers like 2.2.4 thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like `/((\.|\?|\!)\s)|(\?|\!)|(\.$)/g` to get the elements. Here is a pseudo breakdown of each capture group:

1. `((\.|\?|\!)\s)`: any `.`,`?` or `!` followed by whitespace.
2. `(\?|\!)`: any standalone `?`or `!`.
3. `(\.$)`: any `.` followed by `end-of-line`. (this one might be unnecessary depending on the string)

Here is the rough code to get you on track:

```js
console.clear();
var str = 'This is a wordpress plugin. its older version was 2.3.4 and new version is 2.4. But the version 2.4 had a lot of bungs. Can we solve it?';
console.log('"' + str + '"');
console.log('Becomes:');
console.log('"' + str.replace(/((\.|\?|\!)\s)|(\?|\!)|(\.$)/g, ".\n") + '"');
```

The "real deal" would properly have to replace over several rounds to account for the different symbols:

```js
console.clear();
var str = 'This is a wordpress plugin. its older version was 2.3.4 and new version is 2.4. But the version 2.4 had a lot of bungs. Can we solve it?';
str = str
  //"all"
  //.replace(/((\.|\?|\!)\s)|(\?|\!)|(\.$)/g,".\n")
  //"."
  .replace(/((\.)\s)|(\.$)/g, ".\n")
  //"?"
  .replace(/((\?)\s)|(\?)/g, "?\n")
  //"!"
  .replace(/((\!)\s)|(\!)/g, "!\n")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Not necessary, if you want to return back correct symbol, you simply can pass function, to replace method
For exampe:  function(match){return match+"\n"})

which will make it look like this : console.log('"' + str.replace(/((\.|\?|\!)\s)|(\?|\!)|(\.$)/g, function(match){return match+"\n"}) + '"')

or even ECMA6 arrow function : console.log('"' + str.replace(/((\.|\?|\!)\s)|(\?|\!)|(\.$)/g, m=>m+"\n") + '"')

Comment: Well that was running correctly here in the code snippet. Thanks for your answers, well i also create this expression and it solved my problem. **str.replace(/([.?!])\s*(?=[a-z]|[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|")**